# Disable Certain MapTips in Graphics Layer for ArcGIS Silverlight

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

I am using the ESRI Silverlight API to allow users to use the Identify functionality on a map.  The graphics layer on this map is set to use Map Tips, and a pin will be applied to the graphics layer when a user clicks on the map.  However, in specific cases, I want the map tips to be disabled.

I am using the MouseEnter event on the graphics layer to catch each graphic as the user rolls over them.  Once inside, I can determine whether or not I want the Map Tip to show up based on the graphics' attributes.

Is there a way for me to disable the Map Tips inside of the MouseEnter event?  I don't want to disable them for the entire graphics layer.

Answer (score 1):

Graphics have a `MapTip` property as well. `GraphicsLayer.MapTip` is used if this property is not set.

You could play with setting this property on MouseEnter (or when initially constructing the graphic) to try and get your desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider the a custom symbol.  For example the MapTipLabelMarkerSymbol in this [sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#SpatialQuery).